# Architecture or Logic of a Node, Mongo (Capped and Persistent) Socket.io Real Time Web Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-applications, socket.io, real-time

So probably quite a basic question, but want I'm trying to achieve is a web application with real-time functionality using socket.io and mongodb capped collections with tailable cursors (with normal mongodb collections being used for persistent data as well).

For now lets just pretend the application is an online chat system with rooms, multiple users and messages flying about.

The two main problems are as follows:

```
a) When the first initially joins the app, how/where should the initial set of data (list of chat rooms, maybe a count of users next to them) be loaded from...

    -> persistent mongo storage : db.Rooms.find().orderBy({ date : -1 })
    -> retrieved from "memory", a capped collection, some form of stream....

b) When the second user joins, should their initial set of data be loaded from

    -> either of the first two options for (a) or alternatively  or hit the first client up for their "live" version of data
```

Followed by down the track when the first users join a room that has people chatting a way, they need to get the history up to a point.... than the live data... maybe look at older messages... so on and so forth.

Basically at the moment I'm creating socket.io rooms which I subscribe users to based on what "backbone" view they are in and load the "live" data directly to them via socket.io.

I'm primarily stumped about the initial data load and I guess the proper architecture client -> message queue -> db -> message queue -> client(s) sort of setup

Sort of pseudo code below

```
Initialize App and Sockets

==== assumption: application is called chat, has chat rooms, messages flying about in them ====

User 1 socket connect -> join "chat" 

    sockets requests room list (top X rooms) -> mongo db query?

User 2 socket connect -> join "chat" 

    socket requests room list (top X rooms) -> mongo db query? memcache? tailable cursor?


==== messages exist and are continually being sent to chatRoom1 =====

Users 1 joins "chatRoom1" -> socket notifies others a new user has joined

    socket requests user list and top X messages and Y users

User 2 joins "chatRoom1" -> socket notifies others a new user has joined

    socket requests user list and top X messages and Y users (potentially newer messages that user 1)

New Messages follow this process

    // client event handler on a new message, write to div for the correct room
    Client -> socket.on("new message", function(data) { $("#" + data.room).find("div.messages").append(data.message) }

    // client sending a new message, specifies room name and message
    Client -> socket.emit("new message", { "room" : "chatRoom1", "message" : "contents of the message" }

    // Server receives message and does two things
    // a) sends it to other clients of the same room
    Server -> socket.on("new message", function(data) {  io.sockets.in(data.room).emit("new mesage", data)   } )
    // b) stores it in the collection (capped?)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check out this video from 10gen (the mongodb company), it walks you through building an irc chat app with mongodb.   http://www.10gen.com/presentations/building-irc-app-mongodb-deployment-replication-and-monitoring